# How to get current directory name with <windows.h> C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directory

I'm trying to get current directory using win32 api (using [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx)) as a `char` array...
but the following code prints: 004FF56C

```
TCHAR NPath[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, NPath);
std::cout << NPath << endl;
```

What is the problem in this code?

Comment: I suspect you have the `UNICODE` macro defined. Try using `std::wcout` instead.

Comment: wow, thanks!!
but if i want to still use the regular std::cout what should i do?

Comment: @Ruslan Ver you need to change the settings to not use UNICODE, in visual studio , go to project properties and the first page , change `Use Unicode Character Set` to `Not Set`

Comment: You can use the standard [`wcstombs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs) function or the [`WideCharToMultibyte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows function.

Comment: @Raxvan thank you!! solved.

Comment: Even better, don't fall into the trap of using Microsoft's horrible `TCHAR` macros.  It's upsetting how this has infiltrated into user programs, and it's Visual Studio's fault.

Comment: Or : `char NPath[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectoryA(MAX_PATH, NPath);`.

Comment: The current working directory is hardly ever useful. It's a per-process property that can be changed by any thread at any time. Why do you think you need to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that by default, Visual Studio projects use UNICODE for all Win32 API functions. This means that `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t` instead of `char`, so all `TCHAR`-based strings are treated as `wchar_t[]` instead of `char[]`.

1. One solution for this is to use `std::wcout` to output the Unicode string.
2. You can change the project settings to not use Unicode by default, by going to `Project Properties` -> `General` -> `Character set` and change that to **Not Set**. This tells the compiler to map `TCHAR` to `char` and not `wchar_t`.
3. You can convert the Unicode string from `wchar_t[]` to `char[]` by using [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx) or [`std::wcstombs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs).
4. You can call `GetCurrentDirectoryA()` directly.

   ```
   char NPath[MAX_PATH];
   GetCurrentDirectoryA(MAX_PATH, NPath);
   std::cout << NPath << endl;
   ```

Now back to why yout get `004FF56C` or some other random number, it has to do with the implementation of `std::cout` if you take a look at the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) you see this operator:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os, 
                                     const CharT* s );
```

there `CharT` is `char` for `std::cout` and `wchar_t` for `std::wcout`. In case you use mismatched `char/wchar_t` with `cout/wcout` there is [another operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) that is called (one that prints pointer values), not the one that prints text:

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( const void* value );
```